# mySQL insert and delete errors

Tags: mysql, database

I'm new to MySQL and I'm having this kind of problem. The insert is not working but the delete is working

```
INSERT INTO ww SELECT * FROM fff WHERE dates = CURDATE();
DELETE FROM fff WHERE dates = CURDATE();
```

Comment: the insert syntax is `INSERT INTO tablename (columns) VALUES (rows);`

Comment: I'd recommend that you give the manual a quick read on INSERT and sub selects.

Comment: its traditional to post the error message received. you can insert into select, probably the shape of fff is not exactly the same shape of ww. post also the table structures for ww and fff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your sql is fine unless

1. one or more column from fff is not in ww

Easy solution write the query like this -

```
INSERT INTO ww (col1, col2, ...) SELECT fff.col1, fff.col2 , ... FROM fff WHERE dates = CURDATE();
```

Or you can debug your existing --
1. RUN this query in Phpmyadmin `SELECT * FROM fff WHERE dates = CURDATE();` and check how many columns it return and match each column exists in ww .

Answer (score 1):

try this (my recommended) :
for insert = `INSERT INTO yourTable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('yourData1','yourData2','yourData3');`

for Display = `SELECT * FROM yourTable;` or when you using parameter, then simply : `SELECT yourField1, yourField2, yourFiled3 FROM yourTable WHERE dates = CURDATE();`

in your case, you are merge between `INSERT` and `DISPLAY`